# Does customResponseHeaders/customRequestHeaders work with key-value store (etcd)?

Tags: traefik

I set this key:

```
etcdctl set /production/traefik/frontends/blah/headers/customResponseHeaders/X-PoweredBy foo
```

But when I `curl blah` I don't see the header in the response.

```
* Rebuilt URL to: blah/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to blah (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: blah
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 34
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Date: Thu, 08 Mar 2018 05:56:48 GMT
< Server: nginx/1.13.7
< 
* Connection #0 to host blah left intact
```

I've tried many combinations of capitalization and other stuff. But I'm not even sure that the custom header stuff of traefik is supported with the key-value stores like etcd. Is it?

I know that I am successfully setting keys on the frontend I want because this works (i see it change in the dashboard):

```
etcdctl set /production/traefik/frontends/blah/passHostHeader false
```

Can I set custom header stuff using etcd or does it only work with .toml files and with Docker labels?

Answer (score 0):

I found out from the slack channel that indeed custom headers are NOT supported with key-value stores like etcd. But it is planned for v1.6.